# Newman Error: Invalid Protocol : null

Tags: newman

I am getting a Invalid Protocol : null error when I run my postman collection via Newman.

Steps I have followed

1. Installed node js
2. Configured npm registry using
   npm config set registry
3. Configured npm proxy using
   npm config set proxy
   4.installed Newman using npm install -g Newman
4. Tried to run a postman collection using 
   newman run
5. In the result I am getting an error saying

Invalid Protocol : null

Answer (score 0):

Try to writing these commands in your console with your password and user of Windows:

**set HTTPS_proxy=youruser:yourpassword@ip of the proxy:port of the proxy

set HTTP_proxy=youuser:yourpassword@ip of the proxy:port of the proxy**

I hope it helps.